# Magento 2 Knockout Js Not binding customer data and wishlist count after login

Tags: knockout.js, magento2

Magento 2, Cusomer name and wishlist count are not displaying at header links after login. I have noticed that they have used knockout js to bind customer as scope. But not fetching details.Don't know why.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This data is loaded via ajax

`https://example.com/customer/section/load/?sections=wishlist&update_section_id=false`

To fix your issue you need to :

- check that there is no javascript errors. Can be done in browser console = press F12 to open it. fix them if any
- check ajax call response. If there is some errors - fix them